Spinner / Dropdown Menu in Jetpack Compose
Trying to create a dropdown menu with at least 50 items using the compose code below:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Spinner(label: String, options: List<String>) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(options[0]) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = it },
    ) {
        TextField(
            // The `menuAnchor` modifier must be passed to the text field to handle
            // expanding/collapsing the menu on click. A read-only text field has
            // the anchor type `PrimaryNotEditable`.
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {},
            readOnly = true,
            singleLine = true,
            label = { Text(label) },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            options.forEach { option ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(option, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge) },
                    onClick = {
                        text = option
                        expanded = false
                    },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

The code functions correctly but exhibits noticeable lag compared to a View equivalent. Additionally, the menu fails to close when the trailing icon is clicked.
How can I optimize the code to achieve performance comparable to the View spinner and ensure the menu closes when the trailing icon is clicked?

I can confirm the noticeable lag which seems to scale with the number of DropdownMenuItems. I cannot, however, reproduce the trailingIcon problematic, that seems to work fine.

any fix available for the lag?

@EdgeDev can u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001258/dropdownmenu-frame-drops-and-lags-in-jetpack-compose
